# Multiple ViewModels in Kendo MVVM

Tags: javascript, css, html, mvvm, kendo-ui

I have this code that works but I'm not exactly sure if it's the correct way to accomplish what I'd like to do.

Let's say I have a dropdown list of category IDs and whenever the user selects a category the site will pull up the appropriate products for that category. The problem I'm facing is that I feel as though I shouldn't need a separate view model for the results (resultsViewModel). Is there a way to include the results from the ajax call into the original view model (viewModel)?

**JS**

```
    var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    title: "Products",
    Categories: null,
    GetProducts: function (e) {
        var categoryID = $('#drpCategory').val();
        var data = { CategoryID: categoryID };
        $.ajax('/Product/GetProductByCategoryID', {
            dataType: 'JSON',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                // Should this go to current ViewModel?
                var resultsViewModel = kendo.observable({
                    Result: data
                });

            }
        })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just create an additional property on your viewModel for Products, and call viewModel.set("Products", data); in your success function.

```js
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    title: "Products",
    Categories: null,
    Products: [],
    GetProducts: function (e) {
        var categoryID = $('#drpCategory').val();
        var data = { CategoryID: categoryID };
        $.ajax('/Product/GetProductByCategoryID', {
            dataType: 'JSON',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
               viewModel.set("Products", data);
            }
        })
    }
})
```

Then bind your products to that array.  Or you can make it a dataSource and set the data property of it.